# PagerDuty Alert: How to set "Severity" level in Alertmanager

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager, pagerduty

I try to control the severity level of PagerDuty alerts using configuration of Alertmanager.

I hard-coded the `severity` level to `warning` in the receiver of Alertmanager:

```
- name: 'whatever_pd_service'
  pagerduty_configs:
  - send_resolved: true
    service_key: SERVICE_KEY
    url: https://events.pagerduty.com/v2/enqueue
    client: '{{ template "pagerduty.default.client" . }}'
    client_url: '{{ template "pagerduty.default.clientURL" . }}'
    severity: 'warning'
    description: '{{ (index .Alerts 0).Annotations.summary }}'
    details:
      firing: '{{ template "pagerduty.default.instances" .Alerts.Firing }}'
      information: '{{ range .Alerts }}{{ .Annotations.information }}
        {{ end }}'
      num_firing: '{{ .Alerts.Firing | len }}'
      num_resolved: '{{ .Alerts.Resolved | len }}'
      resolved: '{{ template "pagerduty.default.instances" .Alerts.Resolved }}'
```

but still in the alerts generated, the `Severity` level was set to `critical`:
[image]

Is there a way to set the `Severity` level in PagerDuty?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the reason why the `severity` field in Alertmanager receiver configuration is not working - we are using a `Prometheus` (Events API v1) integration in the PagerDuty Service, and according to the specification of PD Events API v1 (https://developer.pagerduty.com/docs/ZG9jOjExMDI5NTc4-send-a-v1-event), there is no `severity` field.

So there are two ways to solve this problem (achieve Dynamic Notification for PagerDuty) - either use Events API v2, or use service orchestration (https://support.pagerduty.com/docs/event-orchestration#service-orchestrations)